# Finding source code of road graph plugin in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, c++

I'm working on a project that I have to model a highway map into a network and apply some network analysis algorithms in that network to get insight into.

I found that QGIS Road Graph Plugin routing pretty well only with raw map data. So I searched for source code of this plugin but it seem that the SVN repository hasn't available any more.
I searched in QGIS Github repository, but still cannot find.

Do you have any idea about where they put that code in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin has been removed from master but you can still find it in the 2.18 branch under https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/release-2_18/src/plugins/roadgraph